# If Spark's data will be cached off-heap, will it have a byte-level specification?

Tags: c++, c, apache-spark

I have learned from various blogs, most notably [this one](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/28/project-tungsten-bringing-spark-closer-to-bare-metal.html), that in the near future, Apache Spark will be cached off the Java heap (in `sun.misc.Unsafe`). What I haven't been able to find is if that data will have a well-known layout in bytes that can be interpreted with C or C++. Does anybody know? If so, will it be a "use at your own risk" specification or a supported API?

The reason I ask is that I have highly optimized C++ libraries that I currently can't use with Spark without copying through the JNI or shuttling to an external process or (equivalently) PySpark. It would be great to be able to run C++ code directly on the raw pointers without copying. (Read-only, of course.)

Does anybody know if there are plans to allow this? Spark has nice support for Scala/Java, Python, and R; it would be nice to add C/C++.

Comment: This would be a better fit for [dev list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/).

Comment: If you feel you need to delete this question because it doesn't fit StackOverflow's format, go ahead, but I wouldn't have found my way to that dev list without having posted here. I think that's an argument for it being useful to SO members.

Comment: I don't think there is anything particularly wrong. It is just any question about upcoming features is purely opinion based unless something is actually implemented, merged and resolved :) But I am glad that url proved to be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, zero323; by pointing me to the dev list, I was able to find the answer to my question.

http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Tungsten-off-heap-memory-access-for-C-libraries-td13898.html

The answer is that this is one of the motivating goals of the project, though it's still early in the design process (as of Oct 2015). There's a [JIRA to track](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10399).